# Using CASE When in Where clause with date parameters

Tags: sql

I am trying to run a query and restrict transactions by date parameters for certain accounts. Has anyone tried this before? do i have to do a sub-select in the case or can i use case in where clause?

I have tried using it in case and didn't work

```
 Select 

    Left(M.Account,4) As Entity, v.Type, isnull(round(-sum(t.debit+t.credit),2),'') As Activity

    From GLM_MASTER__ACCOUNT AS M CROSS APPLY 
    (Values (case  When right(m.account,9) = '1110.0130' then 'A'
                   When right(m.account,9) = '1110.0131' then 'F'
                   When right(m.account,9) = '1110.0132' then 'B'                 
                   When right(m.account,9) = '1110.0133' then 'C'
                   When right(m.account,9) = '2110.0061' then 'D'
                   When right(m.account,9) = '2110.0062' then 'G'
                   When Substring(m.account,6,3) >'000' and Substring(m.account,6,3) < '200' and right(m.account,9) between '3000.0000' and '3999.9999' then 'E'
                                                       When Substring(m.account,6,3) >'199' and Substring(m.account,6,3) < '300' and right(m.account,9) between '3000.0000' and '3999.9999' then 
                    Case 
                        When Substring(m.account,6,3) IN ('271','270') and Right(m.account,9) IN ('3150.0000') Then 'E' 
                        When Substring(m.account,6,3) IN ('271','270') and Right(m.account,9) Not IN ('3150.0000') Then 'G'
                        When Substring(m.account,6,3) NOT IN ('271','270') and right(m.account,9) between '3000.0000' and '3999.9999' Then 'E' End
                   When Substring(m.account,6,3) >'300' and right(m.account,9) between '3000.0000' and '3999.9999' then 'K'            
             End)
             ) v(type) 

    Left OUTER JOIN GLT_CURRENT__TRANSACTION AS T on M.Account = T.account 

    Where (Left(M.Account,4) IN (@Entity) OR '' IN (@Entity)) and
    T.DBID = 'ONNILIVE' and right(m.account,9) Not IN ('3910.0090','3910.0070') and v.type is not null
    and 
    Case When RIGHT(m.acount,9) = '1110.0130' then T.Accounting_Date <= Eomonth(SDate,-3) Else End 

    Group by Left(M.Account,4), Type
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: currently using SSMS 17

Answer (score 1):

```
Where T.Accounting_Date >= 
        Case When RIGHT(m.Account,9) = '1110.0130' Then DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 6, 0) 
             When RIGHT(m.account,9) = '1110.0131' Then DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 6, 0) 
             When RIGHT(m.account,9) = '2110.0061' Then DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 6, 0) 
             When RIGHT(m.account,9) = '2110.0062' Then DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 6, 0) 
             When Right(m.account,9) Between '3000.0000' and '3999.9999' Then @SDate 
        End
And T.Accounting_Date <= @Edate
```